Loading int8 version of llama3 from llama.cpp
I'm trying to load an 8 bit quantized version of llama3 on my local laptop (linux) from llama.cpp, but the process is getting killed due to memory exceeding.
Is there any way around this?
I've already worked with the 4 bit version, and that runs smoothly

If you don't have enough RAM to load the model you can add swap space, but it comes with a heavy performance penalty

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
